# PHP Static variable return on if/else condition

Tags: php, loops, oop

I have a class with bunch of static variable like

```
class staticVars{
    public static $host1 = 'www.host1.com';
    public static $host2 = 'www.host2.com';
    public static $host3 = 'www.host3.com';
    public static $host4 = 'www.host4.com';
    ...
}
```

As I am accessing the variable like

```
$var = staticVars::$host3;
```

Not what I want is based on some condition, static variable should return value on some condition. Like below,

```
    class staticVars{
        public static $host1 = 'www.host1.com';
        public static $host2 = 'www.host2.com';

        if(condition){
            public static $host3 = 'www.host31.com';
        }
        else{
            public static $host3 = 'www.host32.com';
        }

        public static $host4 = 'www.host4.com';

    }
```

How this can not be done, because obviously this is not valid. Also, I don't want to create object first. I need it to be done statically.

Comment: You cannot evaluate conditions outside of methods. You should place that logic into a static method instead.

Comment: what about define a function inside the class for that purpose?

Comment: @mitkosoft That would be accessing a function, not a static variable. I am ignoring that because then I need to change thousands of lines of code.

Comment: Do you need to pass this condition? will the condition change every time you call your properties?

Comment: When does the condition have to be applied? At instantiation time? You could use a function you have only to call once to set all the dependent attributes. Also see the edit in @FelipeElia's post below.

Answer (score 1):

Use static functions instead:

```
class staticVars{
    public static function getHost($number) {
        switch($number) {
            case '1':
                return (condition) ? 'www.host1.com' : 'www.host31.com';

                break;
        }
    }
}
```

and call

```
staticVars::getHost(1);
```

### EDIT

Reading the comments I've saw it's not possible for OP. So, I think that initializing the var through a static method would solve the problem:

```
class staticVars{
    public static $host1 = null;
    public static $host2 = null;
    public static $host3 = null;
    public static $host4 = null;

    public static function initialize() {
        self::$host1 = (condition) ? 'www.host1.com' : 'www.host31.com';
    }
}
staticVars::initialize();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use constant ?

```
class staticVars{
    public static $host1 = 'www.host1.com';
    public static $host2 = 'www.host2.com';
    public static $host3 = _HOST3_;
    public static $host4 = 'www.host4.com';
    ...
}
```

in a `constant.php` file, or `config.php` or whatever you want (it depends on your condition) :

```
if(condition)
{
    define('_HOST3_', 'www.host31.com');
}else{
    define('_HOST3_', 'www.host32.com');
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I can use $GLOBALS for this instead of constants.

Comment: If you prefer, why not. But I think constant is better because static values are not supposed to change once defined. Dont forget to validate if you dont need more help.